# How do I handle [Del] key as an action in a Vala application?

Tags: gtk3, vala

I have a Vala Gtk3 app in which exists a treeview widget displaying a tree of data on each tab of a notebook widget. To handle deleting the selected node from the "working" tree, there's a delete action having the [Del] key as its accelerator. Now if the user selects a treeview node and presses the [Del] key, it works as expected; however, there's a search entry widget contained on the app's header bar and if the user selects text in it to delete and then presses the [Del] key, rather than the text being deleted, the app acts like the user intends to delete the selected tree node instead. Clearly, I'm not handling this correctly. What would be the correct way to go about this? Do I need to check in my on_delete() handler for which widget has focus? This seems wrong given that a Gtk.Entry widget would normally handle deletion of text automatically.